# How to run a F# app in Windows Azure?

Tags: windows, f#, azure, webrole

I have a project that requires me to write a library management system in F# and using Windows Azure for the development. I am quite new to Cloud concept and I don't know what to do as a next step. Is there any way to implement it using Web Forms? If you can help me with the steps I have to take, I can study them and learn.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/, read the introduction, [download the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/default.aspx) and in Visual Studio, select to create a new F# project.

The current SDK only supports **Worker Roles** (background processing) for F#, so no: by default you can't implement Web Forms with F#. You can, however, create a Web Forms project in either C# or VB.NET as a [Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) that delegates all work to an F# library.